# How to get the image path of all running processses as a standard user (XP / Server 2003 and below)?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-xp, windows-server-2003

I am trying to get the full path of all running processes in the system as a standard user without administrative rights on Windows XP / Server 2003. Getting the list of all running processes and handles to them is not a problem (Toolhelp "Process32First" / Native API "NtQuerySystemInformation" / PsApi "EnumProcesses"). My problem is that these calls do not return proper process handles, but some sort of handle that I first have to pass to "OpenProcess" to get a proper process handle that I then can use to query for the full image path (by calling "GetProcessImageFileName" or some low level function). But, for processes not started by the current user, "OpenProcess" fails if I am not an admin.

Can anybody point me in the rights direction on how to retrieve this information? Process Hacker and Process Explorer are able to do it, so it should be possible. I am aware that Process Hacker's source code is available, but as far as I understand it uses some sort of driver to query running processes.

**Correction:** As David Heffernan pointed out in his answer Process Explorer and Process Hacker do not display the full image path on Windows XP when started by a non admin user.

Here's the requested code (written in Delphi):

```
function GetProcessDetails (const th32ProcessID: THandle) : String;

var
    szImageFileName : array [0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
    hProcess : THandle;

begin
    hProcess := OpenProcess (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ,
                             false, th32ProcessID);

    if (hProcess = 0) then
        exit;

    if (GetProcessImageFileName (hProcess, @szImageFileName [0],
                                 MAX_PATH) > 0) then
        Result := szImageFileName;

    CloseHandle (hProcess);
end; { GetProcessDetails }
```

And here's the function that uses "Process32First / Process32Next" to retrieve the process information:

```
procedure FillProcessListToolHelp;

var
    hSnapShot : THandle;
    PE : TProcessEntry32;
    sImageFileName : String;

begin
   hSnapShot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

   PE.dwSize := SizeOf (TProcessEntry32);

   if (Process32First (hSnapShot, PE)) then
       repeat
           if (PE.th32ProcessID <> 0) then
               sImageFileName := GetProcessDetails (PE.th32ProcessID);
       until (Process32Next (hSnapShot, PE) = false);

   CloseHandle (hSnapShot);
end; { FillProcessListToolHelp }
```

Please be aware that "SeDebugPrivilege" has been assigned before making the call to "FillProcessListToolHelp". Also, right now I am only interested in a solution for 32 bit Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you present works as intended and is the best that you can do. You can add a little more diagnostics to it to see better what is going on:

```
hProcess := OpenProcess (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ,
                         false, th32ProcessID);
if (hProcess = 0) then
begin
  Writeln(IntToStr(GetLastError));
  exit;
end;
```

What you will then learn is that when `OpenProcess` is failing, it is because `GetLastError` is returning `5`, aka `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. And that is because, as you yourself have identified, the processes in question are owned by a different user.

Windows security means that your standard user process is simply unable to open a handle to these processes with the necessary access rights. If you wish to obtain information about these processes you will need to execute your code with sufficient privileges, for example by running as administrator.

I believe that the best you can do without admin privileges is to use the information returned in the `szExeFile` member of `TProcessEntry32`.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.TlHelp32;

function GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess: THandle; lpImageFileName: LPTSTR;
  nSize: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall;
  external 'PSAPI.dll' name 'GetProcessImageFileNameW';

function ImageFileName(const PE: TProcessEntry32): string;
var
  szImageFileName: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
  hProcess: THandle;
begin
  Result := PE.szExeFile; // fallback in case the other API calls fail
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, false,
    PE.th32ProcessID);
  if (hProcess = 0) then
    exit;
  if (GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess, @szImageFileName[0], MAX_PATH) > 0) then
    Result := szImageFileName;
  CloseHandle(hProcess);
end;

procedure FillProcessListToolHelp;
var
  hSnapShot: THandle;
  PE: TProcessEntry32;
begin
  hSnapShot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  PE.dwSize := SizeOf(TProcessEntry32);
  if (Process32First(hSnapShot, PE)) then
    repeat
      if (PE.th32ProcessID <> 0) then
        Writeln(ImageFileName(PE));
    until (Process32Next(hSnapShot, PE) = false);
  CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
end;

begin
  FillProcessListToolHelp;
  Readln;
end.
```

---

Now, in the question you state:

> Process Hacker and Process Explorer are able to do it, so it should be possible.

But that is not the case. At least for Process Explorer which is what I use. Here's what Process Explorer, when running as standard user, has to offer for the smss process:

[image]

Having just tried out Process Hacker, I can see that it will yield the information you want, even when not running elevated. So if you wish to do this yourself you simply need to read the Process Hacker and do what it does.

Comment: My mistake -- I for some reason wrongly thought that Process Hacker and Process Explorer are able to return the full image path on Windows XP when executed by a non admin. So David is correct.

Comment: On win 7 process hacker can do it, somehow

Comment: The author of process hacker has an article on how this works for Vista and up:
http://wj32.org/wp/2010/03/30/get-the-image-file-name-of-any-process-from-any-user-on-vista-and-above/

A more thorough overview of these undocumented structures can be found here:
http://www.exploit-monday.com/2013/06/undocumented-ntquerysysteminformation.html

Comment: Neat. I guess that gets you home on Vista but XP is still out of reach.